# Using php mysql group results by column?

Tags: php

I have a table with data  `mobile(id, name, size)`;

```
(1, "Asha 301", "240 x 400");
(2, "Asha 302", "480 x 800");
(3, "Asha 303", "240 x 400");
(4, "Asha 304", "480 x 800");
(5, "Asha 305", "240 x 400");
(6, "Asha 306", "240 x 400");
<?php
    $query = "SELECT id, name, size
              FROM `mobile`
              GROUP BY size Order by display_size ";
    $results = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   foreach ($results as $result) {
        ?>
        <li>
           <?php echo $result['size']; ?>
           <ul>
               <li><?php echo $result['name']; ?></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
<?php
}
?>
```

And result is:

```
240 x 400
   Asha 301
400 x 800
   Asha 302
```

result only get 1 row, how to get all rows ?

```
240 x 400
   Asha 301
   Asha 303
   Asha 305
   Asha 306
400 x 800
   Asha 302
   Asha 304
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707613/how-to-group-result-in-subgroups-in-php

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_object` returns an object, so iterating through it in a foreach does nothing.

Instead, you should use `mysql_fetch_array`, which returns an array of the results,

Answer (score 1):

```
 $query = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `size` FROM `mobile` Order by `size` ";
 $results = mysql_query($query);
 while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
  ?>
    <li>
       <?php echo $result['size']; ?>
       <ul>
           <li><?php echo $result['name']; ?></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: This unexplained snippet clearly does not satisfy the brief of needing the group text once followed by all children of the group.