# Fetch more data inside foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

So I need to fetch data such as section, item names and subtotal of every section from my database and get the grand total of all the items.
I stumble upon the code below and modify it to my requirements.
The code works perfectly but I need to display more data like Item description, Qty, Price, status and so on.
The code below works and have no problem whatsoever but i need more data (description, qty, price and so on) to display in my table but I can't figure out how to do it.
The data I need to display is also in the same row where projectscostbreakdown_areaname, projectscostbreakdown_itemname and projectscostbreakdown_totalcost are.

```
<?php
$projectsid = $_GET['projectrfpid'];
$itemdeleted = 1;
$itemfirstothers = 'OTHERS';
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT projectscostbreakdown_id,
projectscostbreakdown_projectid,
projectscostbreakdown_areaname,
projectscostbreakdown_itemname,
projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription,
projectscostbreakdown_qty,
projectscostbreakdown_costpiece,
projectscostbreakdown_budgeted,
projectscostbreakdown_totalcost,
projectscostbreakdown_note,
projectscostbreakdown_addedby,
projectscostbreakdown_addeddate,
projectscostbreakdown_deleted,
projectscostbreakdown_lastedit,
projectscostbreakdown_lasteditby
FROM projectscostbreakdown WHERE projectscostbreakdown_projectid=:projectsid && projectscostbreakdown_deleted=:itemdeleted ORDER BY projectscostbreakdown_areaname=:itemfirstothers, projectscostbreakdown_areaname ASC, projectscostbreakdown_id DESC');
$query->bindParam(':projectsid', $projectsid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':itemdeleted', $itemdeleted, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':itemfirstothers', $itemfirstothers, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();

$data = array();
$data2 = array();

$numbering = 0; //for item count
$count = 1; //counter use for background color
while ( $row2 = $query->fetch() ) {

if ( empty($data[ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_areaname'] ]) ) {
    $data[ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_areaname'] ]= array();
    $data2[ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription'] ][ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_qty'] ]= array();
}

if ( empty( $data[ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_areaname'] ][ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemname'] ] ) ) {
    $data[ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_areaname'] ][ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemname'] ] = array();
    $data2[ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription'] ][ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_qty'] ]= array();
}
    $data[ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_areaname'] ][ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemname'] ][] = $row2['projectscostbreakdown_totalcost'];
    $data2[ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription'] ][ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_qty'] ]= array();
}
print '<table width="100%" border="0"><tbody>';
$totalSum = 0;

foreach ( $data as $area => $item ) {
print '<tr style="background-color: white;"><td colspan="7" style="text-align: left;"><br /><br /><b><u>'. $area .'</u></b></td></tr>';
print '<tr style="background-color: #AAAAAA; text-align: center;">
  <td width="20%""><b>Item name</b></td>
  <td width="30%"><b>Description</b></td>
  <td width="5%"><b>Qty.</b></td>
  <td width="10%"><b>Cost/Piece</b></td>
  <td width="10%"><b>Subtotal</b></td>
  <td width="10%"><b>Budget</b></td>
  <td width="15%"><b>Note /<br / >Entered by</b></td>
</tr>';
$totalArea = 0;

foreach ( $item as $item => $totalcost ) {
    //while ( $data = $query->fetch() ) {
    $numbering++;
    $count++;
    $class = ($count%2 == 0)? 'white': '#CCCCCC';
    $sum = array_sum( $totalcost );
    print '<tr style="background-color: '.$class.'">';
    print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">'. $numbering .'. '. $item . '</td>';
    print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">';
    print_r($data2);
    print '</td>';
    print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right;"></td>';
    print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right;"></td>';
    print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right;">'. number_format($sum, 2,'.', ',') . '</td>';
    print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right;"></td>';
    print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left;"></td>';
    print '</tr>';
    $totalArea += $sum;
}
print '<tr style="background-color: lightgray; text-align: right;" ><td colspan="6">Section Total: </td><td>'. number_format($totalArea, 2,'.', ',') . '</td></tr>';
$totalSum += $totalArea;
}
print '<tr style="background-color: lightblue; text-align: right;" ><td colspan="6"><b>Grand Total: </b></td><td><b>'. number_format($totalSum, 2,'.', ',') . '</b></td></tr>';
echo '</tbody>
</table>';
?>
```

UPDATE
The output looks like this right now.
I need to include Description and Qty in the output but cant figure how to be done.

Section1
Item Name-----Description-----Qty-----Subtotal
item 1---------------------------------------------1000
item 2---------------------------------------------2000
----------------------------------Section Total: 3000

Section2
Item Name-----Description-----Qty-----Subtotal
item 3---------------------------------------------1000
----------------------------------Section Total: 1000
------------------------------------Grand Total: 4000

Comment: Can you show how your results look like and what you expect? It would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: See updates. Thanks.

Comment: Can you make the structure in your database a little bit more readable? :)

Comment: But perhaps can you show me a picture of how it currently looks like and how you want? I still find some difficulties to completely understand you question. :)

Comment: The output looks like the link. but i need more data to show. like Description and qty. http://i.imgur.com/55bUidK.jpg thanks

Comment: Well, it looks quite simple to me. If you have provided other information about product, why not use same thing but just from different column?

Comment: When im inside the foreach my $row['x'] doesnt work. Im new in php and cant figure it out.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Is it necessary to be with `foreach`?

Comment: And how do you get `subtotal`? With sum or is available instantly in database?

Comment: subtotal is in the database. calculated while processing the value and store it in database.

Comment: Could you still give me an exported data from that table? Or maybe give a screenshot as I currently have some difficulties imagining it.

Comment: Hello http://textuploader.com/58zlh this is a table i exported. i just use text file if you are hesitant to download files to your computer. I use project id 42 specifically for easier reference.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i actually dont have value for the itemdescription in my db but i do have qty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete code (more structured, fixed bugs):

```
<?php

$projectsid = $_GET['projectrfpid'];
$itemdeleted = 1;
$itemfirstothers = 'OTHERS';
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT projectscostbreakdown_id,
projectscostbreakdown_projectid,
projectscostbreakdown_areaname,
projectscostbreakdown_itemname,
projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription,
projectscostbreakdown_qty,
projectscostbreakdown_costpiece,
projectscostbreakdown_budgeted,
projectscostbreakdown_totalcost,
projectscostbreakdown_note,
projectscostbreakdown_addedby,
projectscostbreakdown_addeddate,
projectscostbreakdown_deleted,
projectscostbreakdown_lastedit,
projectscostbreakdown_lasteditby
FROM projectscostbreakdown WHERE projectscostbreakdown_projectid=:projectsid && projectscostbreakdown_deleted=:itemdeleted ORDER BY projectscostbreakdown_areaname=:itemfirstothers, projectscostbreakdown_areaname ASC, projectscostbreakdown_id DESC');
$query->bindParam(':projectsid', $projectsid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':itemdeleted', $itemdeleted, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':itemfirstothers', $itemfirstothers, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();

$data = array();
$data2 = array();

$numbering = 0; //for item count
$count = 1; //counter use for background color
$itemData = $query->fetchAll();
$query->execute();

while ($row2 = $query->fetch()) {
    if (empty($data[$row2['projectscostbreakdown_areaname']]) ) {
        $data[$row2['projectscostbreakdown_areaname']]= array();
        $data2[$row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription']][$row2['projectscostbreakdown_qty']] = array();
    }

    if (empty($data[$row2['projectscostbreakdown_areaname']][$row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemname']])) {
        $data[$row2['projectscostbreakdown_areaname']][ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemname']] = array();
        $data2[$row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription']][$row2['projectscostbreakdown_qty']]= array();
    }

    $data[$row2['projectscostbreakdown_areaname']][$row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemname']][] = $row2['projectscostbreakdown_totalcost'];
    $data2[$row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription']][$row2['projectscostbreakdown_qty']] = array();
}

print '<table width="100%" border="0"><tbody>';
$totalSum = 0;

foreach ( $data as $area => $item ) {
    print '<tr style="background-color: white;"><td colspan="7" style="text-align: left;"><br /><br /><b><u>'. $area .'</u></b></td></tr>';
    print '<tr style="background-color: #AAAAAA; text-align: center;">
      <td width="20%""><b>Item name</b></td>
      <td width="30%"><b>Description</b></td>
      <td width="5%"><b>Qty.</b></td>
      <td width="10%"><b>Cost/Piece</b></td>
      <td width="10%"><b>Subtotal</b></td>
      <td width="10%"><b>Budget</b></td>
      <td width="15%"><b>Note /<br / >Entered by</b></td>
    </tr>';
    $totalArea = 0;

    foreach ( $item as $item => $totalcost ) {
        $count++;
        echo $numbering.' ';
        $class = ($count % 2 == 0) ? 'white' : '#CCCCCC';
        $sum = array_sum($totalcost);
        print '<tr style="background-color: '.$class.'">';
        print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">'. $numbering .'. '. $item . '</td>';
        print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left;">'.$itemData[$numbering]['projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription'].'</td>';
        print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right;"></td>';
        print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right;"></td>';
        print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right;">'. number_format($sum, 2,'.', ',') . '</td>';
        print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right;"></td>';
        print '<td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left;"></td>';
        print '</tr>';
        $numbering++;
        $totalArea += $sum;
    }

    print '<tr style="background-color: lightgray; text-align: right;" ><td colspan="6">Section Total: </td><td>'. number_format($totalArea, 2,'.', ',') . '</td></tr>';
    $totalSum += $totalArea;
}
print '<tr style="background-color: lightblue; text-align: right;" ><td colspan="6"><b>Grand Total: </b></td><td><b>'. number_format($totalSum, 2,'.', ',') . '</b></td></tr>';
echo '</tbody></table>';
?>
```

Basically, what I did (*which might not be the best option but I couldn't think anything better*) was I used `$itemData = $query->fetchAll();` after executing `$query->execute();`. Now if we leave everything the same, table will be empty since pointer is at the last element. Therefore, we must execute again the same query by writing an additional `$query->execute();` right after `$itemData = $query->fetchAll();`.

Now we have basically the same thing as in your example but with one additional variable `$itemData` with all information about items. To bring out description, quantity, etc. now we can use `$itemData[$numbering]['projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription']` where `$numbering` stands for array's index number.

Comment: Hello Edvin, Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately it still doesnt work, No error but no item show up. I got the code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707613/how-to-group-result-in-subgroups-in-php and then just modify it to fit my requirements. this code works, but there are more data i need to display (description, qty etc). An item will have qty, price and totalcost(qty*price which is saved in the database), $sum = array_sum($totalcost), will sum up all the total cost of each item per section.

Comment: @user366966 I see. With `while` pointer is at the last element, therefore, it returns nothing. What if you try `$data = $query->fetchAll();` instead and then use the same `foreach()`?

Comment: It returns nothing. Do you think i can just add items that i need to return in the "while" like $data2[ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_qty'] ]= array(); because its there where  it only works but dont know how to add. I tried it but it says undefined index projectcostbreakdown_qty in line where the foreach so i can not declare it inside the foreach.

Comment: @user366966 I actually might solve this but then I need SQL dummy data (export) from that table (at least a few rows). I could check then myself in my test database.

Comment: thank you so much for your help heres the text file as sql, you can just copy this and import http://textuploader.com/58zlh I use the projectid 42 as sample to make it easier for you.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i dont have value for the itemdescription in my db but i do have qty.

Comment: @user366966 I'll check when I have some free time (maybe in about hour or so).

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated the sqldbtext and added itemdescription http://textuploader.com/58zqr BTW i tried to put this in the  $data2[ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_itemdescription'] ][ $row2['projectscostbreakdown_qty'] ]= array(); and called it in the foreach and i actually able to get the data in array, im not sure how to get the specific rowdata for a specific item. http://i.imgur.com/LRlPUhG.jpg

Comment: @user366966 Ok, I have some free time. I got your DB and code. How exactly would you like to show description? There are a lot of empty arrays right now. Do you want to get from specific row or combine them all?

Comment: Description is per row, I mean one item has description, qty etc. so i want to show whats the description for a particular item, the qty etc. i have some other data but I think I can do it once I get the description and qty.

Comment: @user366966 Got it. Updated my answer with complete code restructure. Hope that works as you expected. If so, don't forget to upvote & mark as accepted (not necessary but really appreciated). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much buddy for your great help and work. It work as expected. I just added another numbering variable for each item as item 1 starts at '0' were it should be '1' other than that its working as I expected it to be. Thank you again. :)