# How do you make list based on different id with the current session of user?

Tags: php

I'm creating cart function for my e-commerce project. I want to create a view item list that has been grouped according to the seller id so it will not get mix.

This is my current code.

```
$sqlq = $Conn->prepare("SELECT c.*, i.name, i.price FROM cart c
                        JOIN info i
                        ON c.id = i.id
WHERE c.id = ? ");
$sqlq->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["id"]);
$sqlq->execute();
$result = $sqlq->get_result();
```

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th width="10%">Product ID</th>
        <th width="10%">Seller ID</th>
        <th width="40%">Product Name</th>
        <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
        <th width="10%">Price</th>
        <th width="15%">Total</th>
        <th colspan ="2">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {        
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["seller_id"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["qty"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["price"]; ?></td>
        <td>RM <?php echo number_format($row["qty"] * $row["price"], 2);?></td>
        <td><a href="#<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><span class="text-danger">Remove</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
            
            $total = $total + ($row["qty"] * $row["price"]);
            $count += ($row["qty"]);
        
        }
    }
       
    ?>

  
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" align="right">Total</td>
        <td align="center">RM <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>
        <td colspan ="2"><?php echo ($count); ?></td>
    
    </tr>
   

   
        
</table>
```

current output of the code:
[image: current output of the code]

What I'm trying to achieve is how can I make the list based on the seller_id? How do I fix the SQL in order to get output like table below?

```
product id | sellerid | product name  | quantity  |
---------------------------------------------------
    4      |  1       | iphone12      | 1         |
    5      |  1       | milo          | 1         |

product id | sellerid | product name  | quantity  |
---------------------------------------------------
    6      |  2       | samsung       | 1         |
```

Comment: So which product name do you want to display? `SELECT c.product_id, c.seller_id, GROUP_CONCAT(i.name SEPARATOR ' / '), i.price FROM cart c JOIN info i ON c.id = i.id WHERE c.id = ? GROUP BY c.seller_id`?

Comment: this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707613/how-to-group-result-in-subgroups-in-php

Comment: @AlexBarker I want to display all the item that the user has choose. But I want to group the item based on the seller id. With my current coding it did not separate the seller id. I want to separate the seller id and put it under different view list.